# Refresh GridView After Data is Deleted From DetailView Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

When user select any record from the GridView then my DetailView is updated based on the selection of the GridView.  So what I am trying to do is that when I delete anything from the DetailView then I want to refresh the GridView so basically I don’t want to show still the deleted record in the GridView.  I have tried to resolve this issue by doing the data bind after my connection and SQL statement but it does not refresh it.  One thing to note is that I am using a Accordion pane but both my gridview and the detailview are on the same pane.  I am not sure if this is breaking anything.  Here is my code:

```
protected void Refresh_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Delete", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID, Name, Address from dbo.MyTable", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the event of the Data view called "ItemDeleted" as follows:

```
  DetailViewName_ItemDeleted(object sender, 
    DetailsViewDeletedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Refresh the GridView control after a new record is updated 
    // in the DetailsView control.
    GridViewName.DataBind();
  }
```

The above code is from the [official MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemdeleted.aspx) for detail view control.

The other way (which I prefer) is to handle the data grid during the `Page_load` procedure so when you press your delete button in the detail view, the page will perform a postback.

So in the procedure `Page_load` you can call another procedure which fills the data grid. The code might be like this:

```
if (isPostback)
{
  FillGrid();    
} 

private void FillGrid()
{

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID, Name, Address from dbo.MyTable", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't show anything where the record is actually deleted so it's understandable that when you re-fetch the data still contains everything.

What you need to do is:

1. Execute a sql statement to delete the record
2. Re-fetch the data
3. Rebind the data.

If you follow those 3 steps it will work.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the event that is called in case of pressing the delete key from the DGV

```
private void DGV_DeleteKeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //enter code here
}
```

Comment: i have tried that but still the same thing... it is not refreshing